# Startup Error Problem

Tags: windows, wubi, startup

I installed Ubuntu with the Windows Installer, reboot laptop and choose Ubuntu in startup options.

But then the console said what Windows cannot be launched and asked for a disk with OS.

Also it said:

```
File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

Condition: 0xs0000098

Notes: Can't load chosen record, because application's missing or damaged.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is this a preinstalled Windows 8 system or does it boot with `UEFI`. If so, Wubi doesn't work. See this instead: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

rollback your previous stage first , and use EasyBCD software to switch between ubuntu and window. its free for home user. Using this software you can select which OS will start first, and also set the initial time . 
download from:- http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

and you can watch youtube how to use EasyBCD